# Vue component not showed in vue dev tools

Tags: laravel, vue.js, components, vue-devtools

I'm using vue js on laravel,
i have two different file app.js and app-filter.js in my resource/js folder

what i want is to call the app-filter.js on specific page but the app js is always called for each page:

in my app-filter.js i have

```
const filter = Vue.component('filter-project', require('./components/filter-project.vue').default);
 
const appfilterproject = new Vue({
    el: '#app-filter-project',
    components: {
        'filter-project': filter
    }
});
```

and in my app.js i

const app= new Vue({
el: '#app',
components: {
'other-component': othercomponent
}
});

so in my page when i call app-filter i have these import

```
<script src="{{ asset('front/js/app-filter-project.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('front/js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

the order is respective

and in my page i call

```
<div id="app">
    <other-component></other-component>
</div>

<div id="app-filter-project">
    <filter-project></filter-project>
</div>
```

the two component are showed in the page but on my devtools it show only my `other-component`

and any event on filter-project component not work , if i remove app.js from import, all thing work well

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using Vue 3 and it is only supported by [Vue.js devtools Beta](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/ljjemllljcmogpfapbkkighbhhppjdbg?hl=en), try to install it and reopen your browser